# Facebook Like Button on FBML Tab

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, fbml

I'm trying to add an FBML tab in facebook that includes a like button.  I want to ask visitors to click the like button before revealing a form.  When they click it, the form would display and then they can complete the form and submit it.

Is this possible?

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think they ever gave a good Like button for FBML.  What you can do, however, is have users like the page, and then wrap things in FBML tags to determine whether or not a user can see the content.  fb:visible-to-connection should do that for you, I think.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/visible-to-connection/